# What is the name of the soundtrack in Dragon Ball Z that plays whenever Goku is about to start a fight?

Tags: dragon-ball-z

I am trying to find the Dragon Ball Z sound track which plays whenever Goku is about to start a fight and other heroic moments. I have browsed a ton of videos but no success. The sound track starts with beats of drums (3 beats), then pause, then 5 beats and so on. Can someone help me out?

Comment: can you find a youtube video of an episode where the music plays?

Comment: I have been trying a lot, but no success so far. I browsed the fight scenes but its always another music, not the drum one. I can remember the music only as a faint memory. Its sort of inspirational kind of music, and as far as I remember, plays when Goku is sort of angry( not sure about the exact moment though). In short the details are a bit blurry, and I only remember those drum rolls.

Comment: its really hard to notice which one by just reading the beats so try [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8MaiCJ9E6xE) for sound track and [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragonball_Z_American_Soundtrack_series) for sound track series.

Comment: Oh boy, i would take that as a last resort. Let me clear the track. It consists of only drums, nothing else. A starting 3 beat(less than a second), then around a 3 sec pause, then 5 quick beats, another 3 sec pause and so on. Can you narrow them down based on this ?

Comment: @Plutoniumsmuggler Isn't [that](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kLwchljYhP8) the theme you are looking for ?

Comment: No. It doesnt contain any other music. Just drums. This one has music as well. Its a short track I can remember now.

Comment: @AGuif....here is one video...https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=HoIlfSw2syw   but the tune in it is very very short compared to what I am looking and not exactly same, but pretty close..(listen carerully drums when goku pats gohan).

Comment: @Plutoniumsmuggler In which episode/fight did you hear that sound?

Comment: I dont remember it..it was long time back..I gave a link of a video above..did you got something from that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the Genkidama (spirit bomb) theme in the Japanese ost I think it als plays when Goku makes the Super Saiya-jin speech

Comment: Thanks a lot. I m really glad someone finally found this. I found the link : http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=jK5z1jU3SMQ . (Good old memories)

Answer (score 0):

[DRAGON BALL Z -Orquesta Sinfonica](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X2soFL4dIac#t=0m45s)

It's the music in this video at 0:45. I can't remember the name in the original soundtrack collection. The majority of the DBZ OSTs come from the movies; this one I believe is from some movie between Freeza and Cell saga.

Comment: What you shown it's a OST of the original japanese from this scene.
What Plutonium smuggler asked belong to the remastered version (you could easily see it in his comments)

Comment: @dragonballfreak . Its very close. But not exact. The beats in my track are slower and little detailed. Thanks for effort, although I doubt I'll ever find that tune again.